# Query for instance_name, port number in format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need result in below format, with current connection port. Can someone help me?

```
servername\instance,3000
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no such query. You cannot query for servers.

Answer (score 0):

The following shows you code you can run as c# Console app to get what you want.  If you are already in SQL Management Studio, then you just need to execute the commands directly:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog=dbname;Data Source=servername"))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName'), SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName')", conn))
        {
            string serverName = "";
            string instanceName = "";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            conn.Open();
            var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr.Read())
            {
                serverName = rdr.GetString(0);
                if (!rdr.IsDBNull(1))
                {
                    instanceName = rdr.GetString(1);
                }
            }
            rdr.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Server name of this connection is: " + serverName + ".  Instance of this connection is: " + instanceName);
        }
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("xp_readerrorlog", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            var param = cmd.CreateParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@ArchiveID";
            param.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32;
            param.Value = 0;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            param = cmd.CreateParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@LogType";
            param.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32;
            param.Value = 1;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            param = cmd.CreateParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@Filter1Text";
            param.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;
            param.Value = "Server is listening on";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetString(2));
            }
            rdr.Close();  
        } 
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Note that if your server is using default instance (as mine does) then instance name is NULL.